# How to get Bokeh to scale scatter plot size according to zoom

Tags: bokeh

Some of the folks on my team, including myself, find it pretty disorienting that in a Bokeh scatter plot, say using the `circle` method, that for an initial autoscale fit of the data on the figure we can dial in a reasonable size for our data, using for example something like `plot.circle( x , y , size=3 )`

However when we interactively zoom into our data the glyph sizes as displayed are invariant to the zoom. Is there a way to have them scale proportionally to the zoom we've dialed into? Something akin to an vector graphics interaction (eg svg). If memory serves me right matlab figures and matplotlib figures should maintain zoom proportionality behavior. To demonstrate the behavior we're seeing consider the first image and the red box I approximately zoom into on the second image.

[image: initial zoom]
[image: focused zoom]

Just as a quick demo using Powerpoint to illustrate the sort of desired behavior...
[image: vector graphic example 1]
[image: vector graphic example 1 zoomed in]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For circles, set the `radius` kwarg instead of the `size` value. (There similar, glyph-specific values for the other glyph-types).

i.e.:

```
plot.circle(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3], radius=0.5)
```

`size` is always rendered in screen coordinates (pixels), but `radius` and the related properties are computed in data coordinates and should change in magnitude with zooming.

Comment: Very good, must have missed  the screen vs scale units... `The size (diameter) values for the markers in screen space units` Screen space units, that explains everything. We ported our matplotlib code to bokeh and inadvertently mapped the former's `markersize` definition to `size` in bokeh. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: circle radius certainly did the trick, searching for the analogous geometric sizing options for my other three glyph uses, `x`, `triangle`, and `inverted_triangle` I didn't glance anything at first shot. Searching the [references](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh-plotting) for other glyphs that use `Enum('screen' , 'data'))` (inspired by `radius_units`) I found the following list...`annular wedge, annulus, arc, circle, ellipse, image, image_rgba, image_url, oval, ray, rect, wedge`. Might be out of luck with the other glyphs I'm using :(

Comment: Yes, markers are really intended as "point" scatter glyphs, so they only have a screen space size. It's possible to extend bokeh, so it's possible you could make custom glyphs that are like markers but that do scale with data zoom level. Alternatively, you can use `patches` to draw various shapes like triangles, diamonds or squares, and those would scale

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good demo by Bryan Van de Ven showing the difference between pixel coordinates (`size`) and data coordinates (`radius`) given in this conference talk:

[Intro to Data Visualization with Bokeh - Part 2 - Strata Hadoop San Jose 2016](https://youtu.be/ZmzNKxQKMhs?t=732)

> ... the point is all of these attributes can be vectorized. We could
>   for instance say size equals you know 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, and now the size
>   is  modulated right. So we have one that has size 2 and one that has
>   size 4. Size is usually in pixels, radius is usually in data dimension
>   units. But all the other ones here as well all the colors, all the
>   visual attributes can be vectorized in this way. You can either give
>   them a single value as we've done for instance with the line fill
>   color, or you can give them a vector of values in which case all of
>   the things are different.
>
> So next exercise here you go to this
>   notebook this is that second notebook "02 - plotting" it is to try to
>   create the same example but now set the radius instead of the size and
>   sort of see what's the difference if you set if you set radius instead
>   of size.