# How can I have the plottetd points stay the same size when zooming in with holoviews?

Tags: openstreetmap, holoviews, datashader, hvplot, geoviews

I am plotting points on a map with holoviews in python and I want to have the plotted points stay the same size even if I zoom in. I am using the bokeh extension.

I have found this post solving the problem for bokeh, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292049/how-to-get-bokeh-to-scale-scatter-plot-size-according-to-zoom). But I have not found a solution for holoviews so far.

Here is some example code:

```
import datashader.geo
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.element.tiles import OSM
hv.notebook_extension("bokeh")

# select some data from dataframe
most_severe = df.loc[df['samples'] >= 1000]
x, y = datashader.geo.lnglat_to_meters(most_severe['lon'], most_severe['lat'])
most_severe_projected = most_severe.join([pd.DataFrame({'easting': x}), pd.DataFrame({'northing': y})])

# plot the data
OSM() * most_severe_projected.hvplot.points(x='easting', y='northing', c='net', 
                                             hover_cols=list(df.columns), 
                                             title='my_plot',
                                            s=10, height=600, width=800)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stay the same size"? I.e., in data space or in screen space?

Comment: the same size in screen space. I want to have the same behavious as described in the link I posted.

Comment: That post shows how to get two different behaviors in Bokeh, not just one. Your posted code isn't runnable without showing how to create `df`, but in any case I can't tell what the issue is if you want points that stay the same size in screen space, because that's the default behavior, as illustrated in the examples at http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Points.html.